# PowerShell: Get javascript direct download link from a web page

Tags: javascript, powershell, redirect

I'm trying to download files from a webpage.
The webpage redirects me to another page (thank you page) which has the known label *"Your download will start automatically in 5 seconds. If it will not start, Click Here."*.
By placing the mouse on this "Click Here" label, I can get the direct download link that will give me the file I need to download.

As I read about, this is a javascript code procedure that works on the client side, uses a phpsession cookie and populates a unique ID and finally gives you the file to download.

Something like:

```
http://website.download.mpla/mpla/mpla/files/_uniqueID_.exe or .zip
```

I want to automate this procedure in order to get all the direct download links and push them all to a downloader software to be downloaded at once without need of clicking.

I use PowerShell v5.0 to write a script to automate the procedure.
I used Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet, I reached the "thank you" page but I cannot reach the above direct download link to get it and write it out to a txt file.

The idea comes from a forum:
http://killtube.org/showthread.php?2322-CODfiles-%28Filefront%29-Closes&p=12749&viewfull=1#post12749

I write the following PowerShell code but I'm stuck. Can you help me?

```
# URL from the page that gives the popup download file
$uri = "http://www.gamefront.com/files/service/thankyou?id=5125790"
# getting the web content and store it in a variable
$wc = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Method GET -SessionVariable s
# Getting the cookies of the webpage that give us the phpsession cookie value
$s.Cookies.GetCookies($uri)
```

And I'm stuck here. I cannot reach the direct download link..
Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: JavaScript indeed works on the client side. It can send additional requests but cannot magically conjure anything that isn't in some HTTP response. What you need is to sniff HTTP requests/responses with a debugging proxy like [Fiddler](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQjBAwAWoVChMI3_aGrvqtyAIVxpYeCh0RWwtt&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.telerik.com%2Fdownload%2Ffiddler&usg=AFQjCNG2AzWa202ZuC1NEfbXx7QsSPnyxQ&sig2=S2k4TEEUmwpCvJQNUEMDQw). Then you can emulate the request that gets the link in PowerShell.